# How can I solve this trouble issue in downloading tensorflow and anaconda?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, intel-graphics, ssd, python3

I have ubuntu 18.04 64 bit . i bought a hard ssd . and gpu is intel haswell i  tried to download anaconda ,but it is interrupted ,lap tope type is hpprobook. and tried to use command-line and follow instruction to download python 3,but the system download only python 2.7 isnt supported by tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is a useless program in Linux. Anaconda is designed for Windows users and duplicates software that is already included in the default Ubuntu repositories. Worse than that Anaconda is troublesome to configure in Ubuntu.

To install tensorflow run:

```
sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip      
python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

The current release of tensorflow for CPU-only is recommended for beginners. GPU packages (*tensorflow-gpu*) require a CUDA-enabled GPU card and NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit software.

I recommend installing TensorFlow in a virtualenv to prevent having to muck around with your system Python packages. The [official TensorFlow installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv) give various options, so you can choose what works best for you. If you choose the virtualenv route, I highly recommend using virtualenvwrapper, which makes using virtualenv far easier.

[This webpage](https://tools.google.com/seedbank/seeds?keyword=mlbasics) has several interactive TensorFlow tutorials that can execute TensorFlow code in a web browser. Don't skip trying at least some of these tutorials. They will help you a lot later on.

Comment: sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip  ,i typed this

Comment: the answer is sudo python-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1).
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 245 not upgraded

Comment: That message is purely informational, not an error message, so it's OK to continue with the next command/instruction.

Comment: my version is ubuntu 18.04 not(9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1)

Comment: i want to install it through anaconda

Comment: Why do love Anaconda so much? All Anaconda does in Linux is makes millions of problems every time you try to install anything. Ordinarily I'd shut up and let you get on with it anyway, but CUDA/TensorFlow/Pytorch is so hard to install even without Anaconda that you should be warned in advance what you, a new Linux user, are in for.

Comment: i want to use anaconde not pip because i can setup my programmes without using internet, for anaconda also i setup linux ,because it is more easy than windows in anaconda .

Comment: installing tensorflow-gpu takes 30 minutes ,is it ordinary time or there is a harddisk problem

Comment: tensorflow-gpu is a huge download. tensorflow is a smaller download than tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: thanks a lot . I typed two commands on terminal then I will search on  virtualenv, I hope to able to help my self ,but i cant i am very thank you for your help

Comment: Run `apt show virtualenv` in a terminal.

Comment: I run $python3 on a terminal ,then typed from $tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
$device_lib.list_local_devices() ,the output isnot as you described ?

Comment: That's OK because you didn't install tensorflow-gpu, you installed tensorflow, so there isn't any output for the GPU. Try running one of the tensorflow [basic tutorials](https://tools.google.com/seedbank/seeds?keyword=mlbasics)